# Are inline functions in C/C++ a way to make them thread-safe?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-safety

I make the following reasoning, please tell me what's wrong (or right) about it:

"If inlining a function duplicates the code in the place the function is called, then the static and local variables are duplicated for each function calling it and if there is only one thread running the function that calls the inlined one at the same time, then the code is thread-safe".

"And, if it doesn't help with static and global variables, does it with code that is creating temporary variables?"

Thanks

Comment: The local variables of a function are always duplicated for each instance of the function being executed.

Comment: Not so if a variable is declared static. Static variables retain values between function calls and are not duplicated.

Comment: Ok, understood. The local variables are put on the stack, right?

Comment: Only non-static local variables are put onto stack. Static locals are not - they are put into per-process global memory. Otherwsie they can't be guaranteed to retain values as the stack space is reused for various functions being called.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you declare a function as inline, it is merely a hint to the compiler. Static variables have a clear definition in the language. If the compiler does inline the function, it is still obligated to keep the static variables shared between all instances of the function. Therefore, they will remain global and have to be protected in a MT environment.

As to the local variables, unless they are used outside of the function, they are thread safe regardless of the function being inlined or not.

Comment: inline declaration may be a hint, however __forceinline is forced in MSVC ;)

Answer (score 29):

Nope, you are wrong. For a static variable, whether it is inlined or not, there is only actually one instance. Inlined functions have no effect on thread safety, one way or the other.

Answer (score 6):

Each thread gets its own copy of the local objects hence there can not be any threading related issues with them whether you make it inline or not.

But if you are accessing a static or a member variable of the class, all the issues related to the multithreading (corrupting the variable, lost updation...) will still be there irrespective of whether it is inline or not.

Answer (score 3):

Inlining and thread safety are orthogonal, i.e. unrelated concepts.

Consider these functions:

```
int factorial(const int n)
{
  if (n <= 1)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  return factorial(n - 1);
}
```

This function cannot be inlined since it is recursive, yet it is perfectly thread-safe.

```
int factorial_2(int n)
{
  int Result = 1;

  while (n > 1)
  {
    Result *= n--;
  }

  return Result;
}
```

This function could be inlined by the compiler, and is still perfectly thread-safe.

```
int RefCount;

void DecRef()
{
  --RefCount;
}
```

This function is not thread-safe regardless whether the compiler inlines it or not.

Comment: thanks for this late response :). I have clear concepts in my mind now, but your code is very illustrative. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are (or perhaps *were*) buggy compilers that duplicate static variables for each inlining of the containing function. This is not intended behaviour.

With a standart-compliant compiler you are guaranteed to have one instance of each static variable regardless of inlining and have to take care of thread-safety yourself.

Answer (score 2):

[Thread safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) has nothing to do whatsoever with inlining. Just because each thread executes a copy of the same code does not make it safe to access shared data. Please make sure to read up on [Thread safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) before you start multi threaded programming.

Comment: Why? The only way to program thread safe is to learn about thread safety. And from what I can see my answer is as of now still the only one that provides you with a link to some reading to get a deeper understanding of the matter.

Comment: Yes, you are right that you give me a link. But for a wikipedia article on thread-safe I don't need to ask in SO. Besides, I ask for the reasons. Anyway, I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would not use static variables within inline functions. Older versions of the C++ standard called for a different meaning than the current one.

NOTE: Historical answer. Not useful today.

Comment: Which version did such thing?

Comment: @curiousguy: At this point I would feel comfortable assuming this answer has aged out. It was possibly reasonable in 2009 but not anymore. Anyway, I have observed the opposite behavior in really old compilers.

Comment: I was pretty sure that even back in 2009, and before, it was clear that "inline" was not "#define but at the AST level" and never meant to replicate the declarations as in copy-paste

Comment: @curiousguy: It alwasy AST level, but putting your inline function in a header file and including it in two source files originally duplicated your `static` member. In 2009, I still had to worry about circa 2000 era compilers.

Comment: At that time it was clear for all C++ std committee members understood that inline was not expected to change the function behavior. I wonder which broken compiler did that.

Comment: @curiousguy: Originally, all of them. It was impossible to express the linkage of a static member in an inline function in traditional object file formats.

Comment: I see: a static in an inline function has no unique definition point, unlike a class static data member. But then, there is no unique point for vtables for classes with no non inline member function either.

Comment: @curiousguy I'm certain that C++98 standard mandated the current way of handling `inline`.  I remember discussions at the end of the 90s regretting the decision by the C committee for C99 to not follow C++ lead for `inline` semantic and guarantees.  I remember at that time, when I was still in love with singletons, using Meyers singleton with the instance function inline (we were targeting the major Unix systems but not Windows).  Implementation wise, it is no more demanding on linkers that templates, common blocks in Fortran or the traditional Unix tentative definition of C global variables.

Comment: @AProgrammer: I'm not going to dig out the VMs to run the old compilers to check what RTTI did, but I explicitly remember templates duplicating in every .obj file, and non deduping in the final executable.

Answer (score 2):

Previous versions of C++ (and current version of C) doesn't acknowledge the concept of threads. It is just not part of the standard. So relying on some compiler optimization to make your code thread-safe is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

inlining has no effect on whether or not a function is thread safe.  For example:

```
inline void doTheThing()
{
   int a = 42; // this is thread safe, but it would be anyway
   vector<int> * answers = getTheAnswers(); // this is not thread safe
}
```

The access to the vector pointed to by getTheAnswers() is not thread safe because there is no code preventing any other thread from executing the code.  Making the function inline does not prevent doTheThing() from being called by multiple threads at the same time.  In order to make doTheThing() thread safe, you need to make sure that either it is not called in parallel, or any shared (non-local) data you do access is protected.

Comment: I didn't say it was thread unsafe; I said it was not thread safe.  That's not splitting hairs.  Understanding the difference between thread safe, unsafe, and not safe is the difference between people who grok multithreading and people who dont.

Comment: Unless you know the implementation of getTheAnswers(), you can't say it is thread safe.  The signature implied by the call (vector<int>* getTheAnswers;) certainly doesn't suggest that it is.

Comment: OK, then it does suggest something to you -- that it allocates a vector and returns it.  Which may or may not be true.  But even if it were true, how does it do that? Does it copy elements from some global vector? Is that global vector's access made thread safe?  The point is: you don't know.

Comment: *sigh* yourself, read my original post. "In order to make doTheThing() thread safe, you need to make sure that either it is not called in parallel, or any shared (non-local) data you do access is protected."

Answer (score 0):

Not at all.

In order to be thread-safe, a function needs to be thread-safe with respect to ANY instance of the function, including itself; multiple threads can execute the same instance of an inlined function at the same time.

Therefore, even if the compiler did what you suggested (which it shouldn't, as others have said), that would still not make it thread-safe.

Answer (score -3):

All static variables in (normal and inline) functions go into heap. Heap is **NOT THREAD SAFE**.